# GetRelativePath is incorrect

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm outputting two files from my program, the paths to which are supplied in user config.

I need to reference one file from the other so was happy to find the Path.GetRelativePath function however, this:

```
Path.GetRelativePath("/Users/ben/file1.txt", "/Users/ben/file2.txt")
```

outputs `../file2.txt`

I can't see how that's correct; I would expect simply `file2.txt` or better still `./file2.txt`

I'm using .net 6.0 on MacOS

There are lots of examples here of how to do this using Uri's, but can someone explain why this isn't doing what I'd expect...

Thanks

Comment: You didn't read [how it works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getrelativepath?view=net-6.0) though. It says that the first path is considered to be a directory, while you pass a filepath

Comment: You can use `GetDirectoryName` around the first path

Comment: That is the answer!  Thank you.  Clearly didn't read the docs properly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Alexey Larionov (see comments); I simply hadn't read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getrelativepath?view=net-6.0) properly; it states "[The first property] is always considered to be a directory".

So easy fix is

```
Path.GetRelativePath(
    Path.GetDirectoryName("/Users/ben/file1.txt"), 
    "/Users/ben/file2.txt")

//returns file2.txt
```